# How to install image for UIBarButtonItem of standard size?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

When I try to add my image to a UIBarButtonItem, it changes its size. Setting the width for the UIBarButtonItem does not help fix the situation.
I would like to add one large image that would suit any device.
When I add an image of 500*500px, the button becomes very wide.
When I add a button of 20*20px, it is so small that I can barely see a point on the panel.

I found several solutions here, but they are all quite old and work when adding a button via code.
Is it possible to do this through Interface Builder?
If not, at least a solution for Swift 4.

In general, it looks very strange and illogical, if it is not possible to add an image to a UIBarButtonItem through the builder interface, so that they remain normal sizes. No wonder this opportunity is there.

[image]

Comment: Take ref : https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/

Comment: You need to slice your images. 1x -> 24px (recommnded by Apple). But I use 30px. Arrange your image accordingly.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Thanks. I am just starting development to iOS and it really helped. Now everything looks great!

Comment: Best of luck for your future. Always try to stick with apple standard instructions and coding good practices so that you will face less issues in development.

Answer (score 0):

Download your images in 3 formats: 25px, 50px and 75px and put behind the image name @1x, @2x, @3x then you can just use storyboard to place them.